# How can I run code in the terminal rather than the output panel using the Code Runner VS Code extension?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

I want to execute code in terminal- not in the debugger.

After downloading all the c/c++ extension in vs-code.
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VHBe5.png)

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   int UserInputOccur;

    cout<<"helloworld";
    cin>>UserInputOccur;
    cout<<UserInputOccur;
    return 0;
}
```

All the compilation and debugging done in debug console only till
( First user input i.e When first `cin>>UserInputOccur;` and then the code in terminated with  `helloworld1020=thread-exited,id="3",group-id="i1"`

Comment: The code runs for me. IHowever,  don't understand what you mean here `All the compilation and debugging done in debug console only till`

Comment: actually the compilation done in debugger panel in VS code not terminal section  panel and the main difficulty is when i take input from user in debugger panel section its takes input and then start printing text  //'helloworld1020=thread-exited,id="3",group-id="i1"'// then no way to give input or write some code in debugger as we can do this in terminal panel of vs code , i used the external terminal compilation true but it doesn't work for me  ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are **using Linux** you can write your code in a file, such as `main.cpp`.

Then you can open terminal -> go to the directory of the file -> run command `g++ main.cpp -o main`.

Now you can run your code on terminal with command `./main`

Comment: actually it does work but need some more effort so that i downloaded the external terminal code-runner and enable this extension    "code-runner.runInTerminal": true,

Comment: Unfortunately `code runner` just execute you program in terminal. No more. This way not allow to debug code.

Answer (score 1):

Put the following in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"code-runner.runInTerminal": true
```

See also https://github.com/formulahendry/vscode-code-runner/blob/master/package.json.