# Vscode not opening terminal

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

My vscode is not opening terminal as I run the program. Instead it shows the output in debug console.

Vscode used to work perfectly earlier but idk what happened or what changed. Even though I'm opening the file provided by uni and we need to just run it as the first task of assignment. But I can't do that. I press on run and it shows build finished on terminal and shows the actual output on debug console instead of MacBook's terminal.

Comment: are you using the Code Runner extension? if so, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/76076895/11107541. Otherwise, how are you running the program? if launch config, show the launch config. If task, show the task config.

Comment: You press run, and it runs. What more do you need? Is your task stated as "press run and make sure the output is shown in the terminal and not in the debug console"?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.